# Retry connection with MongoEngine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

Does mongoengine has a mechanism to retry connection to the DB? I'm looking something like this but with mongoengine library:

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', 
{
    // retry to connect for 60 times
    reconnectTries: 60,
    // wait 1 second before retrying
    reconnectInterval: 1000
},
```

My intention is if the DB connection drop, re-try 10 minutes later. Do re try for 3 times before sending/raising an error.

Answer (score 0):

MongoEngine uses PyMongo as the backend to connect to the database and perform other database operations. You can refer to the following [link](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html) which highlights the parameters that the PyMongo mongo_client API expects.

I think what you are specifically looking for is - ***heartbeatFrequencyMS***

Comment: Thank you for suggesting heartbeatFrequencyMS. I read the documentation of it but it wasn't clear for me the use of this could fit with my need. I edited my question to make it clearer.